# Connecting to AWS MemoryDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-memory-db

I started looking into AWS MemoryDB after spending sometime setting up a cluster. I was able to connect using redis-cli but couldn't connect using redis-py-cluster even though I used the same credentials. Below is my redis-cli command and python script using redis-py-cluster.

Redis CLI

`redis-cli -h HOST --tls -p 6379 -a PWD --user username`

Python code

```
from rediscluster import RedisCluster
startup_nodes = [{"host": "HOST", "port": "6379"}]
rd = RedisCluster(startup_nodes=startup_nodes, username="USER", password="PWD", decode_responses=True, skip_full_coverage_check=True)
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: I get a timeout message that the node is not reachable. But when I use redis-cli, I am able to connect.

Comment: Are you running the redis cli and python code from the same machine?

Comment: Yes both on the same machine

Comment: Dumb question. `"HOST"` is not the actual value you are using in python code

Comment: Lol, no it's not. Actually the python code doesn't timeout now. it just gets stuck without any response until I use ctrl+c to kill it

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the initialization of RedisCluster. Below is the correct parameters especially the ssl=True

`rd = RedisCluster(startup_nodes=startup_nodes, username="demo-user", password="<PW>", decode_responses=True,ssl=True,skip_full_coverage_check=True)`